# Indexing a HDFS sequence file

Tags: indexing, hadoop, sequence, hdfs

What is the best library/way of indexing a very large sequence file (millions of key/value pairs where each value can be of a different length so you cannot have a random access scheme)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about storing the data in HBase? It is built for this kind of thing.